# Trouble with magnific popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I have trouble with Magnific Pop Up in this site: www.angelesmorgan.com (in thew Portfolio area).

When I try to use the popup the console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at jquery.magnific-popup.js:50
    at jquery.magnific-popup.js:13
    at jquery.magnific-popup.js:15
```

I don't understan where is the error.

Pd: is my first web.

Comment: you are using jquery in your code and you do not have the jquery script in your site. Plus, Pop up depends on jquery too, that is why you have the error

Comment: Make sure to include Jquery script before plugin in script